# Mi webservice SOAP trunca un parámetro string a 32767 caracteres

Tags: c#, webservice, string, soap

intentaré resumir.

Tengo un webservice SOAP en C# .NET que tiene una función cuyo parámetro es una cadena string (que es contenido XML que luego deserializo). El problema que tengo es sencillamente que al recoger el string en el webservice, éste me trunca la cadena a 32767 caracteres (el tamaño de un int) y claro, al deserializarlo canta error.

Si hago el proceso con cadenas más pequeñas, la función opera a la perfección, pero es una función que debe recibir cantidad masiva de datos y necesito que trabajecon strings mayores.

He buscado y rebuscado y es posible que la solución esté en la configuración del web.config, pero he probado todas las soluciones que he visto de configuración y ninguna funciona. He probado con:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="publisherBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

pero nada. He probado con:

```
  <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="1048576" maxQueryStringLength="131072" maxUrlLength="262144"/>
  </system.web>
```

pero ni caso, y con:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="131072" maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

y nada. Sospecho que la solución viene en el web.config, pero me escama mucho que si miro el atributo de la clase String llamado "length" éste es un entero, con lo que no podría ser superior al valor que necesito.

He trasteado con la configuración del IIS pero aun estoy en modo "desarrollo" y para probarlo uso el IIS Express que monta Visual Studio .NET

¿Me podría ayudar alguien?

Muchas gracias,

Marcos.

Comment: ¿Ese parametro lo estas sacando de una BD? Si es asi usa nvarchar(max) en lugar de varchar(max)

Comment: No, es un simple parámetro string del método que se llama desde fuera del webservice. Cuando se llama al webservice se le pasa un parámetro: XMLString con un string en XML que se tiene que procesar y si supera los 32767, se trunca. He visto a gente por otros foros a los que les pasa lo mismo, pero si han conseguido solucionarlo no lo han comentado. He probado las soluciones que les plantearon y que he puesto más arriba, pero nada.